# Formatação de duas casas decimais usando lista (Python)

Tags: python, lista

Tenho uma dúvida sobre a formatação de dígitos decimais utilizando duas casas, por exemplo "2.00", fiz este exercício porém estou com um probleminha que não consigo resolver como também não sei se há como faze-lo. Formatar valores de produtos que estão dentro de uma lista.

Exemplo: Caneta - 2.00
Porém a saída fica: Caneta - 2.0

Segue o código:

```
fatura = []
total = 0
valid_preco = False

while True:
    produto = str(input('Produto: '))

    while valid_preco == False:
        preco = (input('Preço: '))
        try:
            preco = float(preco)
            if preco <= 0:
                print('O preço precisa ser maior que 0')
            else:
                valid_preco = True

        except:
            print("Formato inválido, utilize apenas '.'")

    fatura.append([produto, preco])     #Adiciona produto e preço à lista
    total += preco

    valid_preco = False

    sair = ' '
    while sair not in 'SN':
        sair = str(input('Deseja sair? [S/N]: ')).upper().strip()[0]

    if sair == 'S':
        break

for i in fatura:
    print(i[0], '-', i[1])      #Imprime o produto, na frente, preço.

print(f'O total da fatura é: {total:.2f}')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como você deve ter notado, o ideal é manter os números como números enquanto o programa estiver rodando - e só se preocupar em formatar a apresentação quando for ou imprimir o resultado, ou grava-lo num arquivo de textos, ou inclui-lo com texto em alguma outra saída (página html, etc...).

Tentar arredondar o número para duas casas decimais com o `round` é inócuo: a representação interna do número em ponto flutuante na base 2 em geral não é compatível com a base decimal - e o número volta a ter uns "restinhos". Em aplicações de produção que vão lidar com valores monetários, a prática é ou usar sempre números inteiros, e dividir por 100 na hora de apresenta-lo ao usuário, ou usar a classe `decimal.Decimal` do Python que usa uma representação interna em decimal e um número configurável de casas depois do ponto decimal

Para aplicações em que o número não é crítico e podemos usar o tipo de dados *float*, no momento em que o número vira string pra apresentação, você pode ou usar o método `format` das strings como está usando, ou as novas f-strings do Python 3.6  - no seu caso você fez um uso quase correto, mas faltou um indicativo para o Python preencher as casas até o número desejado mesmo que não precise.

Em vez de:

```
print(f'O total da fatura é: {total:.2f}')
```

Use:

```
print(f'O total da fatura é: {total:.02f}')
```

Note o "0" a mais dentro da string de formatação.

Da mesma forma, na linha acima, basta também usar o recurso das f-strings para imprimir os números. Em vez de:

```
print(i[0], '-', i[1])
```

Pode usar:

```
print(f'{i[0]} - {i[1]:.02f}')
```

Em vez de imprimir as variáveis separadas, uma única f-string que formata o nome do produto `i[0]` e o seu preço - e com o preço, usamos o `:` para colocar as especificações de formatação - no caso: ponto flutuante, com duas casas depois do ponto decimal, preenchendo com 0.
A formatação possível depois dos ":" em um campo é bastante flexível, e sua documentação é a mesma que para o método `.format` de strings - está aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Para quem estiver usando uma versão antiga de Python como a 3.5 ou (três batidas na madeira) 2.7, pode ser usado o método `.format` :

```
print('{0} - {1:.02f}'.format(i[0], i[1]))
```

Um detalhe não relacionado diretamente com a sua resposta,mas importante - não é legal usar listas para guardar informações estruturadas - isso é: o nome do produto no índice 0 e seu preço no índice 1. Nada impede, mas já que temos dicionários e namedtuples que permitem fazer a mesma coisa, só que podendo ver o que significa cada campo, isso é melhor.

Então, suas informações sobre cada produto poderiam estar em um dicionário, onde fica fácil para quem estiver olhando o seu código saber o que são i["produto"]  e i["preco"]  em vez de i[0] e i[1].

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! Sua explicação foi muito limpa e esclarecedora.
Realmente não me toquei de como utilizar o format no print da lista e fiquei meio perdido

Comment: Expandi um pouco mais agora - veja desde o começo de novo.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas jsbueno! Realmente ficou muito mais legível e fácil de compreender desta forma, vou colocar em prática todas as dicas que passou. Obrigado mais uma vez, esclareceu mais que meu professor hahaha